# How To Resolve Custom Property Name In XAML For a Winforms UserControl Hosted In WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, interop

I've got a usercontrol that I wrote for an XNA based tile editor.  This is a winforms based control that I am now trying to host in a WPF application.

I am using a WindowsFormsHost control to embed the winforms user control.  On the winforms usercontrol I have a custom property called XnaBackground that is of type Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.  I can see the property fine in the XAML in IntelliSense but when I try to set it I get a message in my XAML window that says 'Cannot convert "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Blue"'.

I've tried to use a custom IValueConverter but since the property is not a dependency property nor is the control a dependency object the binding doesn't work.

Here is the property declaration on the winforms control:

```
    [Category("Appearance"), DescriptionAttribute("Gets/Sets a value indicating the background color to use.")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public Color XnaBackground { get; set; }
```

And here is the XAML from my WPF application:

```
<Window x:Class="TileEditorWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TileEditorWPF"
    xmlns:winforms="clr-namespace:TileDisplay;assembly=TileDisplay"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="WindowLoaded">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:XnaColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                      Background="Transparent"         
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"             
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <winforms:TileDisplayControl XnaBackground="Blue" x:Name="tileDisplay1" OnDraw="TileDisplayControl_OnDraw" OnInitialize="TileDisplayControl_OnInitialize" />            
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</DockPanel>
```

I'm not a WPF expert so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.  I've been banging my head for the last 4 hours and google searches have led me nowhere.  It's such a niche problem that it's difficult to find any kind of trending with this particular subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `TypeConverter` which knows how to convert the `"Blue"` string value you set in the `XnaBackground` property into a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` type.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx

Because you didn't create the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color` type/don't have access its source there is no way for you to put the `[TypeConverter(typeof(ToXnaColorConverter)]` on the type to point to your converter.

However you can put that attribute on the `XnaBackground` property instead. Thus, when a "string" is set on your `XnaBackground` property, it goes through your `TypeConverter` .... which should interpret the string and provide a suitable `Xna.Framework.Color` value.

```
[Category("Appearance"), DescriptionAttribute("Gets/Sets a value indicating the background color to use.")]
[Bindable(true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ToXnaColorConverter)] 
public Color XnaBackground { get; set; }
```

- http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2008/04/10/strings-to-things-or-how-xaml-interprets-attribute-values.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546926(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I understand Value Converters and have written a few for pure wpf projects in the past.  My issue is that I cannot decorate the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color class with the needed attribute.  I suppose I could do an ugly hack and inject the attribute at runtime but that just seems unclean and not very maintainable.  Another choice is to create a bridge type to bridge between the XNA type and an enum I create myself to represent the color which I can then add the attribute to.  That solution is almost as unattractive as injecting the attribute at runtime.

Comment: I ran out of room for the above comment.  At this point I may just use a string property and do an Enum.TryParse on the property before rendering the control.  Not the most ideal and I won't get intellisense but this is a small aspect of my design and I don't want to get mired in details which is kind of hard with WPF - lots of power but a pain to use when first learning since there are like 15 ways to do a thing in WPF but only one right way.

Comment: You don't need to decorate the Xna.Framework.Color class....as mentioned above, you can just put the attribute on your property in your Control...it will then use your converter to convert the string into the Xna Color.

Comment: That was it!  I missed that detail, thank you so much for pointing out the relevant piece.  Thanks!